# How can I use a SQL query to retrieve data on a database sever?

Tags: excel

I have connected to a SQL server in Excel . I want to be able to import data from a table located on the server. However this table is too big to import into Excel, I'm talking millions of rows. I only want to import certain data into Excel, for example only import the data where the date is between a certain range. Where can I do this in Excel? If there are any alternatives to retrieving data from a large database please let me know.

Comment: Which version of Excel?

Comment: @MarkStorey-Smith 2010

Comment: Try the [Power Query add-in](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/download-microsoft-power-query-for-excel-FX104018616.aspx).

Comment: @MarkStorey-Smith: That seems to have licensing limitations if OP is still on Office/Excel 2010.

Answer (score 1):

In EXCEL, from the **Data** ribbon, **Get External Data** tab, select **From Other Data Sources** -> **From SQL Server**.

Follow the wizard to connect to your server and create a query.

Comment: How can I create a query? It gives me the list of tables on the database but it doesn't give me an option to create a query

Answer (score 0):

If you can define the T-SQL query to filter the rows to a specific date range, create a view and choose the view object within Excel instead of the source table.